# Summernote: preloading text issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, preload, summernote

I'm using summernote v0.6.1 and bootstrap v3.2. Unfortunately, I'm not able to preload text to the editor. The text is always placed under the editor. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

This is my Code:

```
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/codemirror.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/theme/monokai.min.css" />
    <link href="/frameworks/summernote/summernote.css" />
    <link href="/frameworks/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="summernote">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-beta.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/formatting.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/frameworks/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $('.summernote').summernote({
                height: 200,   //set editable area's height
                codemirror: { // codemirror options
                    theme: 'monokai'
                }
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
```

I cannot point the error... how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `$('.summernote')` is finding your DOM node? I think you have to add an `id="summernote"` to your div so that jquery find it. I might be wrong but that's how I do it.